# Show data in datagridview from multiple sources

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this code:

```
        DataTable s = produseTableAdapter.GetData();
        DataTable t = produse_magazinTableAdapter.GetData();
        foreach (DataRow row in s.Rows)
            if (row.ItemArray[2].Equals("consumabile"))
            {
                t.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

The problem is that dataGridView1 shows the data from :

```
        DataTable t = produse_magazinTableAdapter.GetData();
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you take a row from your first table and add to your second table.
This is not possible directly with Rows.Add
I think you should use

```
t.ImportRow(row);
```

or

```
t.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray, false);
```

Of course, assuming your table have the same schema and there are no primary key violations.

From your question is not clear if produse_magazinTableAdapter.GetData() is empty or not.
If it's ok to start with an empty table you could create a DataTable with the same schema using 
t = s.Clone(); and then filling the rows with ImportRow or LoadDataRow

Comment: And if primary key violations exists, how could i resolve them ?

Comment: You can create a new datarow with the correct values and add it to t. However, doing it this way you will loose you PK of the row in s.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to merge to two datatables together, then use a filter on the datatable.

You can actually just simply merge the two datatables into one.  However, you need to ensure that the datacolumns are the same name and type.  Example:

```
DataTable s = produseTableAdapter.GetData();
DataTable t = produse_magazinTableAdapter.GetData();
s.Merge(t);

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = s;
bs.Filter = "YourColumnName LIKE '%consumabile%'";
//OR
bs.Filter = "yourColumnName = 'consumabile'";
```

Note: YourColumnName refers to whatever the column is named at ItemArray[2] according to your code.  You can use this binding source on your datagridview like so:

```
this.grid_yourGrid.DataSource = this.bs;
```

This brings both datatables together just like that.  See the MSDN for further info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

For the merge:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx

For the binding source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx

Hope this helps!